# Whats the best way to use mysql_result in php 5.5?

Tags: php, mysql

As it is deprecated, I will need to change my all code which contain mysql_result. Since this may take long time, I am looking for a simplest possible option.

Normally I would use this:

```
$varname=mysql_result($result_query,0,"settingName");
```

now I found a function which may be a replacement:

```
$varname=mysqli_fetch_row($result_query)[0];
```

But in this case, I am unable to see which setting I am getting from database. Also, when I change an order in database, I will need to update all numbers.

How can use a function which I can use a similar syntax?

Comment: The best way would be to use MySQLI, as Mysql_* functions are depreciated

Comment: While you are at it you should upgrade PDO to at least have a sane API imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$varname = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query)['settingName'];
```